# Replacing symbols in a list only for particular elements

Tags: python, list, find

I have thousands of sentence elements in a list. However, many sentences are not readable. Thus, I want to ignore those sentences in the replacement process. Fortunately, those sentences have similar patterns.

**Updated**

This is the sample list I have:

```
sentence = ['"//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb\n',
        '"// How are you? \n',
        '//# Hello world \n',
        '// sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,asdhhi3242jlfaoiuq3r'
       ]
```

I want to replace the symbols such as `/`, `#`, `\n` etc. with a single space `' '` in all sentences, except the unreadable elements. The unreadable elements always have a pattern contains `sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64`.

This is my code using Python 3:

```
text = []
for i in sentence:
    isbase64 = "sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64"
    if i.find(isbase64):
        pass
    else:
        word = i.replace("\n"," ").replace("/"," ").replace("#"," ")
        s = ' '.join(word)
        text.append(s)
```

But the output is an `empty list`. Is there something I need to change?

Expected output:

```
text = ['How are you?','Hello world']
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in:

`sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset:utf-8;base64`

it should be

`sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64` with **=**

```
sentence = ['"//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb\n',
        '"// How are you? \n',
        '//# Hello world \n',
        '// sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,asdhhi3242jlfaoiuq3r'
       ]
text = []
isbase64 = "sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64"
for i in sentence:
    if isbase64 in i:
        pass
    else:
        word = i.replace("\n"," ").replace("/"," ").replace("#"," ")
        s = ' '.join(word)
        text.append(s)

print text
```

And use more pythonic approach `if string in otherString`

Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. Sorry... But the result still an empty list. No difference.

Comment: How is that possible? If I ctrl+c ctrl+v it, it works like it should. It prints :
`['"       H o w   a r e   y o u ?    ', '        H e l l o   w o r l d    ']`

Comment: Yes, now it works. Sorry, I write in python 3. So the `print` command should followed by `()`. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
sentence = ['"//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb\n',
        '"// How are you? \n',
        '//# Hello world \n',
        '// sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,asdhhi3242jlfaoiuq3r'
       ]

print([x.replace("\n","").replace("/","").replace("#","").strip() for x in sentence if 'sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64' not in x])
```

Above code is a comprehensive version of below:

```
text = [] 
for x in sentence:
    if 'sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64' not in x:
        text.append(x.replace("\n","").replace("/","").replace("#","").strip())

print(text)
```

Comment: Could you please make a step by step looping process in a different line? Because after replacing the symbols, I need to do another process before appending to the new list.

Comment: @Yusufsn, Hope this is fine for doing other process.

Comment: Thanks, you save my time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks mostly functional - you just made a typo!
You defined `isbase64` with the text `...charset:utf...` when your sentence parts contain `...charset=utf...`.

Comment: I think I didn't make any typo. `isbase64` is a variable, and `sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset:utf-8;base64` is the value in this variable.

Comment: @Yusufsn: Well, yeah, of course there's no typo anymore, as you edited the question to remove the typo. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize at the beginning. Then, I just realized I made a typo. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`i.find(isbase64)` is returning an int not a boolean.

If i does contain isbase64 it returns the position (e.g. 5 in the first case) else it returns -1 (e.g. in the second string).

If you replace the if by: `i.find(isbase64)!=-1` it should work (or use isbase64 in i).

Edit: you need also to replace the line with isbase64= by `isbase64 = "sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64"` (you had a typo there)

Edit2: you also need to print the `text` in order to see the result i.e. `print(text)`

Comment: I edited the typo. Thanks, but still, it doesn't work.